# Facebook share image wrong on post not on debugger

Tags: facebook

I am trying to find a solution to my weird problem before breaking my laptop..
I have the following blog https://4moms.gr and when i try to share a post on facebook the preview in the facebook popup windows is correct but when i click to post it the image shown is the site's logo.

Example
https://4moms.gr/slider/to-savvato-2-oktovrioy-to-school-work-amp/

og:image tag is present in the view source but in the Facebook debugger i get the classic error
"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags." event though the image is shown in the debugger and that the og:image url is correct in the debugger too. I have tried YOAST i have tried manually importing code to create OG tags but still the same error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your HTML is malformed.

You have span tags in the `head`. Facebook's debugger sees this, and assumes the `head` must have ended and the `body` started, and it didn't find any `og` tags so far - hence it reports the properties are missing.

If you scroll down in the debugger to "Scraped URL: See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" you'll see the problem as FB sees it.